# Alguém sabe como fazer esse programa em C? Estou tendo dificuldades

Tags: c

Implemente,  em  C,  um  programa que,  dado  um  número  máximo  de  nós,  armazene  uma  Árvore Binária de Busca AVL e possibilite que o usuário realize as seguintes operações:

a) Construção  da  árvore:  Forneça  funções  para  as  operações  básicas  desta  estrutura: busca, inclusão e exclusão (lembre-se de considerar o balanceamento).

b) Impressão de percursos: o programa deve permitir que o percurso seja feito em pré-ordem, ordem simétrica e pós-ordem.

Comment: Você [já fez essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/561557/70). Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o campo de comentários desta aqui está desativado, mas o da original pode ser usado normalmente. No quadro de fechamento tem link com orientação de como melhorar aquela pergunta para reavaliação.